# Struct to JSON in Big query google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I have a query which has an ouput as below attached screen shot. Here is the query

```
#standardSQL
select
visitNumber,
visitId,
fullVisitorId,
hits.customDimensions
from table_a 
left join UNNEST(hits) as hits limit 10;
```

[image]

Below is one row and I want the output of customDimension as JSON as below

[image]

I tried using TO_JSON_STRING function in big query, it didnt give the output as below. I also tried ARRAY, ARRAY_CONCAT but couldnt get it above format. Appreciate if some one can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and can be good start for you to tweak for your specific needs

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  visitNumber,
  visitId,
  fullVisitorId,
  (
    SELECT CONCAT('[',STRING_AGG(CONCAT('{"',CAST(index AS STRING), '":', '"', IFNULL(value, ''), '"', '}'), ','), ']') 
    FROM UNNEST(hits.customDimensions)
  ) AS customDimensions
FROM table_a  
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(hits) AS hits 
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have a another question related to this, couldnt get an answer there, appreciate if you can help. here is the question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48508317/string-byte-to-string-big-query?noredirect=1#comment84014189_48508317