# String byte to String - Big query

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I have the below query and it produces data with `\"` added. Not sure if it is string byte causing this problem because `string_agg` produces string byte as output.

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  visitid,
  fullVisitorId,
  hits.hitNumber,
  TO_JSON_STRING(ARRAY(
    SELECT
      AS STRUCT productSKU,
      ARRAY(SELECT STRING_AGG(CONCAT('{"',CAST(index AS STRING), '":', '"', IFNULL(value,''), '"', '}'), ',')  FROM   UNNEST(customDimensions))  as productCustDimension
    FROM
      UNNEST(hits.product) p)) AS product
FROM
  table_a
LEFT JOIN
  UNNEST(hits) AS hits
  LIMIT 10
```

Below is the output it is producing. In the product column, the `productCustDimension` value is what i am taking about, with addition `"\` characters added.

[image]

I found a way to get rid of extra characters I mentioned using replace function, but it kind of becomes too dirty. I am looking if there is a better way of doing it. I want the product column as below

[image]

Comment: This problem happens (invariably) because you're encoding the value as a string twice, when you meant to do it once. I'm not familiar enough with SQL to tell you where that's happening.

Comment: I bet it's between the `CONCAT` and `STRING_AGG` bits. Looks like both are outputting a string.

Comment: If the character `"` is present in your JSON then it should be escaped (that's what BQ is doing by adding `\` otherwise you won't have a valid JSON). You can test with simpler values and get the same result: `SELECT to_json_string(['"5"', '"6"'])`. If you want a valid json then you probably shouldn't remove those from your output.

Comment: The escape character for big query is \ and I tried SELECT to_json_string(['\"5\"', '\"6\"']), but no luck

Comment: my comment ended up being rendered wrong hehe. I meant BQ adds the \ character. if you run the query I suggested you'll see same results you are getting in your query already.

Comment: ok, so wondering what would be the solution then ?

Comment: @LijjuMathew - I would say that there are too much here involved and it gets to messy - I would suggest you to simplify your question by presenting example that focused only on what you want to fix so we might be able to help. also some sample data is important to provide!

Comment: Ok, I want the query result of below query without \" in the result                  SELECT
TO_JSON_STRING(ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT productSKU, ARRAY(SELECT STRING_AGG(CONCAT('{"',CAST(index AS STRING), '":', '"', IFNULL(value,''), '"', '}'), ',')  FROM   UNNEST(customDimensions))  as productCustDimension
    FROM
      UNNEST(hits.product) p)) AS product
FROM table_a

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the " character which is escaped in [TO_JSON_STRING](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#to_json_string). Try running the query like so:

```
...
ARRAY(SELECT STRING_AGG(CONCAT('{',CAST(index AS STRING), ':', '', IFNULL(value,''), '', '}'), ',')  FROM   UNNEST(customDimensions))  as productCustDimension
...
```